# add image to transparent section

Tags: imagemagick, imagick, imagemagick-convert

I have an image with a couple of transparent boxes. I need to insert some specific images in to the transparent boxes. I tried several convert commands but couldn't end up with a solution.

I am using Windows 10 and imagemagick is working on my CLI with no issues. Hope someone can point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say this 500x400 image is your starting image and it has transparent holes in it at 10,10 and 250,250.

[image]

Now, let's say you have two Mr Beans, `bean1.jpg` and `bean2.jpg` like this:

[image]

[image]

Let's lay it out on a red background so you can see what is going on. We'll resize `bean1.jpg` and place him in the area of the top-left transparent hole, then we'll set up `bean2.jpg` for the bottom-right transparent hole:

```
convert -size 500x400 xc:red  \
   \( bean1.jpg -resize 101x101! -geometry +10+10   \) -composite \
   \( bean2.jpg -resize 131x131! -geometry +250+250 \) -composite \  
   result.png
```

[image]

Now let's do that again, but this time, overlay the original image so the Beans peek through it:

```
convert -size 500x400 xc:red  \
  \( bean1.jpg -resize 101x101! -geometry +10+10   \) -composite \
  \( bean2.jpg -resize 131x131! -geometry +250+250 \) -composite \  
 image.png -composite result.png
```

[image]

On Windows, you have to change the backslashes into carets, so `\(` becomes `^(` and `\)` becomes `^)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark, this was the method I implemented. Cheers!